# First payment default and sum of tardy days in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    the_debt_id varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_paid timestamp, 
    the_debt_due date NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('LMUS01', '2019-05-02 09:00:01', '2019-05-02'), 
       ('LMUS01', '2019-06-04 10:45:12', '2019-06-02'), 
       ('LMUS01', '2019-07-05 15:39:58', '2019-07-02'), 
       ('LMUS02', '2019-05-03 19:43:44', '2019-05-07'), 
       ('LMUS02', '2019-06-07 08:37:05', '2019-06-07'),
       ('LMUS02',NULL, '2019-07-07'),
       ('LMUS03',NULL, '2019-05-07'),
       ('LMUS03',NULL, '2019-06-07')
```

I want to calculate the first payment default (if the first element of each the_debt_id is NULL as 1, order by the_due_date), the sum of tardy days (the days passed after the_debt_due) and the quantity of payments. This is the expected result:

```
the_debt_id    first_payment_default    tardy_days    payments
LMUS01         0                        5             3
LMUS02         0                        0             3
LMUS03         1                        0             2
```

I tried this code:

```
SELECT the_debt_id, 
SUM(the_debt_paid::date - the_debt_due) AS tardy_days, 
FIRST_VALUE(the_debt_paid)::int first_payment_default,
COUNT(*) AS payments  
FROM my_table
GROUP BY the_debt_id
```

But I guess the first sum will give me null for the last the_debt_id, and I don't know how to extract the first value from a GROUP BY clause. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, you can use:

```
SELECT the_debt_id, 
       COALESCE(SUM(the_debt_paid::date - the_debt_due), 0) AS tardy_days, 
       (MIN(the_debt_paid) IS NULL) as first_payment_default,
       COUNT(*) AS payments  
FROM my_table
GROUP BY the_debt_id;
```

I'm not sure if you can have a `NULL` followed by another value in another row.  But your example data has no such examples.

Comment: Hello @Gordon Linoff, I added two additional rows, and in the last debt_id the NULL is followed by another NULL. Thank you.

Comment: @Manu . . . Actually the above logic works for the modified data.

Comment: Hello @Gordon Linoff, yes, I tested the code and worked fine!. Perhaps the only question I have is the `MIN(the_debt_paid) IS NULL` clause, because I don't quite get if it's converting the field to NULL or if it'is evaluating a condition. Thank you!

Comment: @Manu . . . The minimum is `NULL` only if all the values are `NULL`.  This is equivalent to:  `count(*) filter (where the_debt_paid is not null) = 0`.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you very much for your time @Gordon Linoff, have a great day!